# Is it possible to read multiple lines from textfile and export it to their respective jtextfields?

Tags: java, user-interface, io, jframe, jtextfield

[image]

```
private void loadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("reload.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        koontf.read(br,null);
        baamtf.read(br,null);
        sachitf.read(br,null);
        fakertf.read(br,null);
        phonsekaltf.read(br,null);
        lauretf.read(br,null);
        yeontf.read(br,null);
        aguerotf.read(br,null);
        agnistf.read(br,null);
        lokitf.read(br,null);
        lawliettf.read(br,null);
        ryuzakitf.read(br,null);
        br.close();
        koontf.requestFocus();
        baamtf.requestFocus();
        sachitf.requestFocus();
        fakertf.requestFocus();
        phonsekaltf.requestFocus();
        lauretf.requestFocus();
        yeontf.requestFocus();
        aguerotf.requestFocus();
        agnistf.requestFocus();
        lokitf.requestFocus();
        lawliettf.requestFocus();
        ryuzakitf.requestFocus();

    }catch(IOException e) {

    }
}
```

> Is it even possible to put each of them to a certain textfield?Like 12 to jtextfield1,10 to jtextfield2 and so on...I've tried some tutorials and can't really figure it out.

Comment: better, persist as a json and read it back and set into the respective field. for a reference have a look at https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all your textFields in an array and then iterate over that array while you are reading the text file. Like this:

```
JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[10];
// ... init your textFields here

int line =0;  // first line will be first textfield and so on
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("reload.txt"));  // use Scanner instead of FileReader, it's easier :) 
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){   // as long as you did not reach the end of the file
    textFields[line++].setText(scanner.nextLine()); // get the next line and put it in the respective textfield
}
```

However, in this case you have to make sure that there is a textfield for every line or that you do not read more lines than there are textfields.

for example:

```
while(.....){
   ....
   if(line==textFields.length){
       break;
   }
}
```

Another thing to notice will be, that the order of the lines has to correspond to the order of your textFields.

**Edit**
I have to add, that all this can work without any problem. But it is not a very elegant solution. What happens when you change your UI and the Textfields are in a different order? Or there is an important new line in your textfile but no TextField in your UI?

**Edit 2**
The code from your comment does not show how you put the JTextFields in your array. My Guess is that you are using some IDE to create the GUI, so you should have a `initComomponents();` call or something in your constructor. In this case, remove the line `JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[10];` from your `loadActionPerformed` method and put it in your constructor like this:

```
public class MyClass{

     private JTextField[] textFields;

     public MyClass(){
         initComponents();
         this.textFields = new JTextField[10]  // where 10 is the number of lines in your textfile AND the number of JTextFields you have in your GUI
         // then fill the array (by hand if you like)
         this.textField[0] = koontf;
         this.textField[1] = baamtf;
         // and so on..
     }
```

**Edit 3**
Just to make it clear, this is what you need to make the program run. Let's say your class is called `MyClass` then it could look like this:

```
private JTextField[] textFields;  // this creates your array

public MyClass(){        // this is the constructor of your class (I don't know how it is called) 
    initComponents();    // auto generated code from NetBeans to initalize your GUI elements
    // init your array
    textFields = new JTextField[12];  // 12 if I counted correctly
    // fill it
    textFields[0] = koontf;
    textFields[1] = baamtf;
    textFields[2] = sachitf;
    textFields[3] = fakertf;
    textFields[4] = phonsekaltf;
    textFields[5] = lauretf;
    textFields[6] = yeontf;
    textFields[7] = aguerotf;
    textFields[8] = agnistf;
    textFields[9] = lokitf;
    textFields[10] = lawliettf;
    textFields[11] = ryuzakitf;
}

private void loadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    int line = 0;
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("reload.txt"))){
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            textFields[line++].setText(scanner.nextLine());
            if(line == textFields.length){
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    koontf.requestFocus();  // you can only call request focus on one element at a time (it does not make sense to call it on all textfields
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to use a `Collection` instead of an `Array`. It's size can be altered easier.

Comment: Good point! My personal preference is the  `ArrayList<JTextField>` because the order of the elements does not change (in this specific case)

Comment: private void loadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[10];

    int line =0;  
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("reload.txt");
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    textFields[line++].setText(scanner.nextLine());
    if(line==textFields.length){
       break;
    }    
    }
    }

Comment: im also using Printwriter so that I can change the numbers in the textfile.When I press the Exit Jbutton it stores the data to the textfile

Comment: You didn't show how you fill the array - see my edit for that. I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to write the data back to the textfile - so don't worry-.

Comment: could you please show me an example on how to fill the array? cause when I run the program it gives me an error. really sorry for the trouble

Comment: and I'm using netbeans Jframe

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer (*Edit 2*). There I show you how to fill the array. I guess you created a TextField with NetBeans and called it `koonf`. Then NetBeans will write a method for you that's called `initComponents()`  (it's hidden and you can't change it directly) and inside the `initComponents()` there is a line `this.koontf = new JTextField()` somewhere. That's all OK as it is.  Somewhere in the top of your file is the constructor of your class, and there you should see the line `initComponents();`. Fill the array after that line with this: `textFields[0] = koontf;`

Comment: Update: I've tried the edit3 and it displays on the koontf "reload,txt" instead of the numbers.

Comment: @Gamedroids when I press the load button it displays on the koontextfield the title of the textfile instead of its contents

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `new File("...")` to make the scanner read the file. Corrected **Edit 3**.